# Use loguru with alembic

Tags: python, logging, alembic, loguru

I want to use Loguru as the Alembic logger handler.
Do you know if and how I can do it?
I only know there are some logging properties inside alembic.ini

Right now I'm seeing the two loggers mixing things up in my console:

```
2021-10-25 23:12:59.484 | DEBUG    | __main__:main:19 - program started
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
2021-10-25 23:12:59.484 | DEBUG    | __main__:main:19 - Hello World!
2021-10-25 23:12:59.484 | DEBUG    | __main__:main:19 - program ended
```